# How to use same labels for shared x axes in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to translate two separate figure into one figure with sharing x axis. But there are something that I'm missing. For styling and ticks I normally use the codes

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\mathrm{2\theta\ (deg)}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\mathrm{Intensity\ (a.u)}$')
plt.xlim(15,80)

plt.legend(loc=4,prop={'size':10})
params = {'legend.fontsize': 18,
      'axes.labelsize': 18,
      'axes.titlesize': 18,
      'xtick.labelsize' :12,
      'mathtext.fontset': 'cm',
      'mathtext.rm': 'serif', }
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)

plt.tick_params(
axis='both', which='both',   
right='off', left='off',    
top = 'off', bottom = 'off',
labelleft='off')
```

Now, I need to apply it for this shared figure. These includes following:

- No ticks will be on figure.
- Axes labels will be shared.
- It would be better to load text files inside a loop.

What do I need to know for these improvements?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import loadtxt
import matplotlib

f = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.001)

data = loadtxt("ES1.txt",float)

POS = data[:,0]
ESD = data[:,1]

ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
ax1.plot(POS, ESD, color="blue")


data = loadtxt("ES2.txt",float)

POS = data[:,0]
ESD = data[:,1]


ax2 = plt.subplot(312, sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot(POS, ESD, color="red")


yticklabels = ax1.get_yticklabels() + ax2.get_yticklabels()
plt.setp(yticklabels, visible=False)


plt.savefig('shared_xrd' + '.png', dpi=600,  bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is the image you show the one being produced by the code? If so, I don't see the problem. Be reminded that when asking about an issue with some code, it is necessary to stick to [ask] and to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank your for your suggestion. I have edited my post, I hope now is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that the following code is more like you want it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

params = {'legend.fontsize': 18,
      'axes.labelsize': 18,
      'axes.titlesize': 18,
      'xtick.labelsize' :12,
      'mathtext.fontset': 'cm',
      'mathtext.rm': 'serif', 
      "xtick.bottom" : False,
      "ytick.left" : False,
      }
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)

f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.001, bottom=0.2)

colors=["blue", "red"]

for i in [0,1]:
    data = np.loadtxt("ES{}.txt".format(i+1))
    POS = data[:,0]
    ESD = data[:,1]
    axes[i].plot(POS, ESD, color=colors[i], label="data{}".format(i))
    axes[i].legend(loc=4,prop={'size':10})

# make ticks invisble
axes[0].set_yticks([])
axes[1].set_yticks([])

plt.xlabel(r'$\mathrm{2\theta\ (deg)}$')
plt.xlim(15,80)

#create subplot just for placing the ylabel centered on all plots
shadowaxes = f.add_subplot(111, xticks=[], yticks=[], frame_on=False)
shadowaxes.set_ylabel(r'$\mathrm{Intensity\ (a.u)}$')

plt.savefig(__file__ + '.png', dpi=600,  bbox_inches='tight')  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly! I also want Intensity (a.u)  (ylabel) centered and read the data from .txt files that are in the same directory with the script which first column is POS and second ESD for every text files in that directory. Thank your @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: This give me KeyError: 'i'. My text files names are as: ES1.txt, ES2.txt. I have tried to change the range as for i in [1,3]: but doesn't worked. Now I'm working to use

`for i in glob("*.txt"):
    POS, EDS = np.genfromtxt(i, unpack=True)
    axes**[i]**.plot(POS, ESD, color=colors[i], label="data{}".format(i))
    axes**[i]**.legend(loc=4,prop={'size':10})`

I might use 2 for loop and appropriate value for the [i] since i is a filename I need an integer.

Comment: So if your files are ES1.txt, ES2.txt etc, you might use `np.loadtxt("ES{}.txt".format(i+1))`. I edited the answer.